# angularjs success and then success returning right respond while then not responding

Tags: angularjs

I dont get to know difference between then and success I posted my controller and view part if i used success it works for me but I used then it doesnot produce the output says not data found in console then also provide the correct array dont know why it does not reflecting into view part in correct way can any one please suggest and tell about difference as well thanks in advance

```
    crudApp.controller("UsersController",function ($scope,$http,$timeout,localStorageService,cfpLoadingBar,$location,$route) {

        cfpLoadingBar.start();

        var token = localStorageService.get('token');

        //console.log(localStorageService);

        $http({
        url:base_url + 'api/loadUsers',
        method:"GET",
        withCredentials:true,
        headers:{'token':token}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            //console.log(data);

// It provides the correct result but i use then it does not return correct ans says No data found

// i used this code

//.then(function(data){

            $scope.list = data;
            $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
            $scope.entryLimit = 10; //max no of items to display in a page
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter
            $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
            //here data is response from server. You can check status, headers, configuration settings too.
            cfpLoadingBar.complete();
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            //do something here. Error occurd while fetching data from server
            cfpLoadingBar.complete();
        });

        $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
            $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
        };

        //delete user
        $scope.delete_user = function(did) {
            var token = localStorageService.get('token');

            if(token != null) {
                swal({   title: "Are you sure want to delete this record?",   text: "",   type: "warning",   showCancelButton: true,   confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   confirmButtonText: "Yes",   closeOnConfirm: true },
                function(isConfirm){
                       if (isConfirm)   {
                                    var url = base_url + 'api/deleteUser/'+did;
                                    $http({
                                    url:url,
                                    method:"DELETE",
                                    withCredentials:true,
                                    headers:{'token':token}
                                    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                            $location.path('/users');
                                            $route.reload();
                                    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                        //do something here. Error occurd while fetching data from server
                                    });
                            }
                });
            } else $route.reload();
        };
    });


    <tr ng-repeat='data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit' data-ng-class-odd="'odd'" data-ng-class-even="'even'">
                                        <td>{{ data.id }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ data.email}} </td>
                                        <td>{{ data.mobile }} </td>
                                        <td class="action"><a href="#/newuser/{{ data.id }}">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript://" data-ng-click="delete_user(data.id);">Delete</a>
                                </tr>
                                <tr ng-show="filteredItems <= 0"><td align="center" colspan="5" style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">No records found.</td></tr>


                            </table><br /><br />
                            <div ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
                                <div pagination="" max-size="10" ng-model="currentPage" boundary-links="true" total-items="filteredItems" items-per-page="entryLimit" class="pagination-small" previous-text="&laquo;" next-text="&raquo;" first-text="&lt;" last-text="&gt;" rotate="false">

                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about `success()` (and `error()`). It's deprecated and thus shouldn't be used anymore. Always use `then()`.

Besides chaining, the main difference between `success()` and `then()` is that `success()` takes 4 arguments: `data`, `status`, `headers`, `config`; whereas `then()` takes a single argument: the HTTP response object, which has 4 fields: `data`, `status`, `headers`, `config`.

So, when you had

```
.success(data) {
    // do something with data
```

Replace it by

```
.then(response) {
    // do something with response.data
```

When you had

```
.success(data, status, headers, config) {
    // do something with data, status, headers, config
```

Replace it by

```
.then(response) {
    // do something with response.data, response.status, response.headers, response.config
```